# Restricting javax.servlet.Filter to specific URL pattern

Tags: java, filter, aem, sling

I'm trying to implement a Filter for a project in Adobe CQ 5.6.1. Seems nifty to be used for doing some, say, authentication stuff for each page that gets displayed.

I've read up on the documentation on [Filters](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html) and I've coded my annotations this way:

```
@SlingFilter(
        label = "Filter implementation",
        metatype = true,
        generateComponent = true,
        generateService = true,
        order = 1,
        scope = SlingFilterScope.REQUEST
        )
@Properties({
    @Property(name="service.description", value="A Filter"),
    @Property(name="sling.filter.pattern", value="/some/path")
})
```

I've compiled my code and looked up the logs, but somehow, it doesn't seem to get filtered for that specific path indicated in the sling.filter.pattern. I don't seem to find much samples on how to implement this so I'm somewhat in the dark about this feature. What I'm sure of is I don't want this Filter to run on every URL that gets loaded.

Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the support for pattern was added for [Sling Engine 2.4.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-4294?jql=project%20%3D%20SLING%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%20%22Engine%202.4.0%22%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC%2C%20priority%20DESC%2C%20created%20ASC) and AEM 5.6.1 is using `Sling Engine 2.2.8` and the AEM 6 is using `Sling Engine 2.3.10`. Hence they might not be behaving as expected. I might not be entirely right, hence leaving it to the experts to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the question's comments, the `sling.filter.pattern` service property on Filters is only supported with V2.4.0 and later of the the `org.apache.sling.engine` bundle. I have updated the docs at http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/filters.html to mention this.

Comment: Thanks @Bertrand & @rakhi4110! I've double-checked with my POM and this seems to be the case indeed. I am using 2.2.8. The question is, would there be incompatibilities in my CQ 5.6.1 setup if I attempt to use Sling 2.4.0 just to get the sling.filter.pattern feature working properly?

Comment: I cannot tell off the top of my head but sling engine 2.4.0 is likely to require other bundle updates, which might get in the way. The following command provides the details, that's a lot of changes: svn diff https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/tags/org.apache.sling.engine-2.2.8/ https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/tags/org.apache.sling.engine-2.4.0/